# Undo Change button in Documentation is broken

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, documentation

For quite some time now, the <kbd>Undo Change</kbd> button on Documentation edits has been broken.

Steps to reproduce:

- Click the <kbd>Undo Change</kbd> button on an edit
- Choose a reason
- Click the <kbd>Create Rollback Draft</kbd> button.
- Submit the rollback by clicking the <kbd>Publish Edits</kbd> button

At that point, I get this error:

> Version is not valid in this context

This used to work, but lately it fails every time with this same error:

[image]

Using Chrome:
Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report! From my initial investigation... what seems to be happening is that the versions in the Android tag don't match the inline versions used in one (or more) of the examples.

In this specific case, the example that trips up validation contains the following directive: `<!-- if version [gte 2.3-2.3.2] -->` and version 2.3.2 is not defined.

I'll have to spend some more time digging into the underlying cause here - not sure at the moment if the versions were edited after that revision was created and we didn't clean up correctly or if we didn't validate the inline versions on example creation well enough or what.

I'd also expect the inline version to have custom formatting and it looks like that's failing as well due to the invalid version being specified, but it's failing silently and further obscuring the situation.

Comment: Thanks Adam! Will be nice to have this back once it's fixed!